# Firebase & Xcode 8: Add "Remember Me" Check Box to Login & Insert Activity Indicator View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, firebase

I am not very familiar with Firebase and I want to create a "Remember Me" Checkbox in Xcode 8 so that a user can use that feature to login if he/she checks the "Remember Me" checkbox.

I would also like to insert an Activity Indicator View after a user taps "Login" but I failed. That little spinner thing just keeps spinning and stays on the screen all the time. I want to dim the screen and have the spinner spin after a user taps "login".

Here are my codes.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "background")
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)

    }

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    //Login Action
    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {

            //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

                if error == nil {

                    //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                    print("You have successfully logged in")

                    //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {

                    //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking us to write the code to display and hide an activity indicator? Are you asking how to dim the screen? What is connection to Firebase?

Comment: Mainly to display and hide an activity indicator. I tried it in storyboard (by dragging it to the view controller) but I think there are some code work to be done.

Comment: Firebase wise, I am not sure if there is a way to add "remember me" functionality that utilize specific firebase functions. Or maybe there is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Firebase so that tag should not be part of the question, and the question should be rephrased to: *How to show/hide an activity indicator* (which there are a number if existing answers to). Also, your followup comment needs clarification; *remember me functionality that utilize specific Firebase functions*. What functions are you referring to? Are you asking how to store data in Firebase or how to call a specific function? Is that perhaps a separate question?

Comment: I think I might have put up too many questions in the same post, I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using UIActivityIndicatorView (the spinner) is pretty straight forward. The question is a bit unclear but here's how to implement it.

Drag and Activity Indicator View to your view. By default, the indicator is hidden by default. You can see that in the attributes inspector Hidden is checked.

To show and start the indicator spinning here's one way

```
self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
```

then to stop and hide it

```
self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
```

In your case, you are going to want to show it when the user taps the login button.

You are going to want to hide it *within the closure* following the Firebase login function.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

     self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true //hide the spinner

     if error == nil {
           //proceed to next step
     } else {
          //handle the error
     }
})
```

As far as the rememberMe checkbox, you would save that setting in the UserDefauts.

When the app starts, it reads the userDefaults and can either auto-log in the user, or ask them to log in.

The downside is that you will also need to save the user name and password in the UserDefaults which could be a security risk. (it could be encoded which would help).

The [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) is pretty well documented in the Apple's Developer Library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your code for activityIndicator (spinner), but, you must do two things:

1. show and start animating the activity indicator when user clicked on login button
2. when the login success or fails you have to stop animating and hide the activity indicator

Regarding the persistence of login data (user/password) you need to work a little bit more, and I believe isn't related with Firebase. The best approach is to use keychain and touchID to avoid to write constantly the user/password text, you can check this tutorial to see how is applied https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That is a new way of thinking! Thanks for that. Is there a way, like, putting a button below login button, says "or use Touch ID to Login", and so they can use Touch ID?

Comment: Of course, all apps with login and auto login have it. https://support.1password.com/touch-id-ios/